# Chrome Extension - Background script accessing IndexedDB (No store)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a Chrome Extension and leveraging Content + Background Script. As per my implementation, I am creating an IndexedDB store and storing some data into it (File object). I am able to retrieve/ list this data in Content Script.

But when I try to access the same DB and store from Background Script, Things become mysterious. There is no Database, no Object Store. None of it is present. I used Chrome Developer Tools to verify this behavior.

Is this the default behavior, OR am I really missing something?

Comment: IndexedDB is a per-origin storage which means that in your content script you're using the web site's origin. The background script however runs in a chrome-extension:// URL origin so its IndexedDB is not related to the web page.

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm Noted

Answer (score 0):

I also have this problem but I solved this by sending data to background script through google chrome api:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(allData: allData);
```

and listen this data into background script.

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener();
```

After that I were opened IndexedDB object store and put/add data into DB.

If your question is this then send data to background script and then access it.